# Warning messages keep appearing in RStudio notebooks in chunks unrelated to the warnings

Tags: r, warnings, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am starting to use RStudio notebooks, and I am still trying to understand how some of the things work.
I do not understand why some produced warning messages are kept and appear when executing code that is completely unrelated to the message. For instance, I have a document with several chunks, where the last of them produces the warning

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
5: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
6: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
7: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
8: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
9: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
10: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
11: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
12: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
13: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
14: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
15: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
16: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
17: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
18: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
19: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
20: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
21: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
22: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
23: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
24: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
25: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
26: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
27: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
28: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
29: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
30: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'perc.goal.met.period'.
There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I am ok with that warning. But later, I thought I would load one additional library to the first of the chunks (where I load them). After running that chunk, I get:

````
```{r echo=F, message=F, warnings=F, include=F}
# Load libraries
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rasterVis)
```
There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
````

If I see the warnings, they are those I printed before.
Why am I seeing them here? I am seeing this also in other chunks also unrelated to the variable `perc.goal.met.period`. If I see the warnings, they will stop appearing for a while, but at a moment that I am still not able to anticipate, they will eventually reappear at some point.

Is there a logical explanation for this behaviour? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This happens to me all the time. If I edit and save an rmd (I think that's the key), then the next command I enter in the console brings back every warning in the session 50x over.

Comment: Oh! So it doesn't happen only to me. Maybe it is just a feature to remind you that there are warning somewhere in your code. Thanks for your comment Frank!

Comment: I think it happens when you cache a chunk the warnings come back later. I had that happen to me.

Comment: That might be right, that was my case

Comment: Related I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864262/persistent-warnings-from-earlier-commands (no real solution although some more speculation)

Comment: Useful: `assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())`

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are running the chunks interactively or compiling the document at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will see warning messages until you clear them out. Running warnings() function does not do that.
To clear warnings you can execute the following command:

```
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())
```

The best approach though is to fix your code so the warnings are not produced. One way to deal with it is to use `tryCatch()` in R.

You can also disable all warnings by using `supressWarnings()` function, but this is not recommended since this will prevent you to see any of them.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that this occurs in RStudio while my code still has the error, even if this is not run (for example, when I leave some wrong code to be revised later). When I delete, change or convert into comments the relevant lines, this behavior ends. I guess that this is caused by the RStudio interpreter. It would be interesting to know if people using base R have the same problem.