# How to suppress warnings with ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, callback, warnings

`ggrepel` allows to avoid overlapping text labels by repeling labels too near from each other.
The algorithm depends on viewing window size, and a callback occurs when window size is changed.
If the algorithm doesn't manage to avoid overlaps for a given window size, warnings are issued :

```
Warning messages:
1: ggrepel: 178 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps
```

I would like to suppress these warnings, independently of the value of `max.overlaps`, because they might come delayed and out of context.

The reason for the delay is probably a callback after first print or after changing viewing window width, see example below :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

N <- 50
data <- data.frame(x=1:N,y=rep(1,N),label =  paste0("Text",1:N))

ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_text_repel(aes(x=x,y=y,label=label),hjust=0, vjust=0, box.padding = 0.5, max.overlaps = 20)

# If the viewing window width is OK, no warning!

#  Execute anything in console
1
#[1] 1
# This is OK!
```

[image]

```
# Now reduce window width with mouse

# No warning yet

# Execute anything in console
1
# Warning messages:
#   1: ggrepel: 41 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 2: ggrepel: 41 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 3: ggrepel: 41 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 4: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 5: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 6: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 7: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 8: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
# 9: ggrepel: 47 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
#[1] 1
```

[image]

I tried `suppressWarnings` and `withCallingHandlers` to no avail:

```
withCallingHandlers(
  suppressWarnings(ggplot(data)+
    geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_text_repel(aes(x=x,y=y,label=label),hjust=0, vjust=0, box.padding = 0.5, max.overlaps = 20)
    )
,  warning=function(w) {
  if( any( grepl( "ggrepel", w) ) ) invokeRestart( "muffleWarning" )
})
```

Comment: I suppose `g <- ggplot...; print(suppressWarnings(g))` isn't really an option?

Comment: @Sirius, unfortunately this isn't sufficient, probably due to the callback!

Comment: @Waldi I might have solution for you: I am working on a R package not publicly available yet, and one of the functions I made is dedicated to handling warnings when you draw ggplot2 plots.
If you wish to have access to it and give a try to the function, could you share here your Github username, so that I can grant you access to it ?

Comment: @Waldi Actually, maybe doing `assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())` would be enough to stop the warnings from being displayed again and again ?

This is the suggestion I offer here:  https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/187#issue-818048871

Comment: @Yoann, thanks for your suggestion. I tried `assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())` and it actually flushes the warnings so that we can control when they occur. However, this doesn't disable them, and a new flush is needed as soon as the window size of the `ggrepel` plot is changed

Comment: @Waldi Then this is more of a dev issue. Keep an eye on the issue I created (the one from the previous link): it got labeled few hours ago, so developpers might adress it sooner or later.
Otherwise, as I offered, I can share with you my github R package and you can give a try to the function I made to handle warnings on ggplots (it is based on the warning message string). I haven't tested it on such issue, but maybe it can help.
You let me know ! I just need your Github username.

Comment: @YoannPageaud, thanks for the link to te issue you created, I'll follow that up. My GitHub username is `Waldi73`

Comment: @Waldi I granted you an access to the repository.
Please follow the README to install the package. Once installed, the function you can try is `warn.handle()`.
If you have issues during install or when using the function, just create an issue in the repository.
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore the warning messages by setting the global warning level as below:
`options(warn=-1)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure it answers my question though : I wan't to remove delayed `ggreprel` warnings, not all warnings.

Comment: Do you need the plot at all time? Why can't you just dev.off() after printing the plot? Else I would probably switch to knitr/rmarkdown to avoid this issue.

Comment: `warn` options are unfortunately not enough to avoid described behaviour. Of course, erasing the plot removes the warn problem, but the question is how to avoid warnings on this specific `ggrepel` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting max overlaps:

```
options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of `max.overlaps` but my question was "I would like to suppress these warnings, independently of the value of `max.overlaps`" because allowing `Inf` makes output very difficult to read on a small window.